# Spring boot with Spring security automatically stopped working after some time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring boot application and using Spring security in it.

Whats happening is, after some time may be 24-28 hours it stopped working. By stopped working I mean, user gets the default spring security login page and when he login nothing works.

Basically all the protected API stopped working and the **logs prints nothing**, it just stopped. I tried many different solution but nothing is working.

It starts working when I restart the application.

I thought this is happening since more sessions might be piling up and the application is not removing the session. So, I added a session a timeout and verified that the session is not there, still this is happening.

Also when that happens, all the public API still works and logs print data for them

the below configuration I am using :

```
http
                .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sping", "/ping","/gridsearch/completerequest","/cache/refresh","/searchtest/sessionsList").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession().maximumSessions(1);
```

Comment: If it's a memory leak (your comment about sessions), a profiling tool should be able to uncover that. It sounds like the requests might not be getting processed; you could turn up the logs to TRACE by adding logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE -- you should see several Spring Security logs for each request at that point.

Comment: Hi @jzheaux I tried the same, found out when the user logs in it goes through jdbcTemplate.queryForObject and this is blocking the complete flow. Any idea why this blockade never removed, I thought if the connection is not available it will through an exception.

Comment: It may be a connectivity issue -- I wonder if you use connection pooling and if those connections are being correctly recycled or discarded. It sounds like a different question, though, and I'd encourage you to update this question with the correct tags and description or close it and write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jzheaux, I figure out the problem was not in Spring Security, it was in the jdbcTemplate.

I was using the BasicDataSource of dbcp2. I haven't provided the timeout to it, hence the jdbcTemplate was waiting for the connection for forever, keeping  the application suspended.